# Maven war plugin ignores .properties file

Tags: maven

I have a simple project with maven using the maven war plugin.  When I clean the project and run mvn package the conf.properties file I have is always left out of my war file.

The conf.properties file is located at src/main/java/conf/conf.properties.

Any ideas on why this file is ignored?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you want to package your property files, put your property files in src/main/resources. This is the generic location for property files for all maven builds.

Answer (score 10):

In case you are unable to change the location of the properties file, you can add something like the following in your pom to indicate the alternate location.  Refer to [this](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) as well.

```
<resources>
  <resource>  
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/conf</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: I did de same, but now I'm having encoding problems. Some tip?

Answer (score 0):

At war plugin level you can define encoding as shown below:

```
           <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                       .........
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this follow in the pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```